# How to customize html of one form field in a form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I need the user to enter data into a form in my django app. I am currently doing this like so:

forms.py: (using model form)

```
class BabysittingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Babysitting
        fields = [
            'title',
            'pay',
            'start_date',
            'end_date',
            'num_children',
            'babysitting_address',
            'babysitting_day_of_week',
            'babysitting_start_time_of_day',
            'babysitting_session_length_hours',
            'description',
        ]
```

Here is my models.py:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    employer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="jobs")
    hired_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    location = models.CharField(default="None", max_length=40)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=JOB_CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    pay = models.FloatField()
    hourly_pay = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('jobs:detail', kwargs={
            'job_pk': self.id
            }
        )

class Babysitting(Job):
    num_children = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    babysitting_address = models.CharField(default="None", max_length=40)
    babysitting_day_of_week = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=DAYS_OF_WEEK_CHOICES)
    babysitting_start_time_of_day = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    babysitting_session_length_hours = models.FloatField()
```

Here is my layout:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block title %}{{ form.instance.title|default:"New Job" }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ form.instance.title|default:"New Job" }}</h1>

        <form action="" method="POST">
            {% bootstrap_form form %}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Post Job" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I need to change the appearance of the pay form field to this:

[image]

I know how to style it this way but I don't know how to change the form template to do this.

How do you customize a single form's appearance in django?

Sorry I should have been more specific, I want to replace one of the form fields with this html (bootstrap):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to add CSS classes, ids etc to this particular form field?

Comment: Yes I need to style it. @nik_m

Comment: @TomFinet if any of the answers have helped you, please mark the correct and close your question, regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `django-widget-tweaks`

If you need to customize your field class, you can render one by one and to add a class to each field

ie, in your template

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block title %}{{ form.instance.title|default:"New Job" }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ form.instance.title|default:"New Job" }}</h1>

        <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <!-- ie field 1 -->
            {% render_field form.field1 class+="form-control other_class" %}
            <input type="submit" value="Post Job" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Documentation about `django-widget-tweaks` [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks)

Comment: If the below answer helped you to resolve your issue, please mark it as accepted. It's a good practice in StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style your form with custom CSS classes, ids etc you should override the `widget` class attribute of the `Meta` class of your form. More on this in [overriding the default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields).

Example:

```
#  forms.py

from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Babysitting

class BabysittingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Babysitting
        fields = [...]  # as is
        widgets = {
            # add here any css classes or attributes per field (on the specific widget)
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'custom-class', 'id': 'custom-id',}),
            'pay': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'another-class', 'id': 'another-id',}),
        }
```